# Android Capture URL from the clipboard

Tags: android, url, clipboard, capture

I'm currently working on project, Android Internet Download Manager. In order to download the file, the user has to copy the URL that he wants to download. What I need is the code to acquire the copied URL from the clipboard, so that I can download that particular file I acquired from the clipboard. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
String textOnClipboard = clipboard.getText();
```

Then you can check if it is indeed a URL, and continue parsing from there. You may want to review the [documentation on `ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html).

Comment: Or have a look at the Copy and Paste documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#framework